# How to do feature engineering for integer column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a code assignment using Apache Spark. It's customer data analysis using Spark.

I need help to identify correct way to solve one of the query.

```
val bankText = sc.textFile("/tmp/resources/bank-full.csv")

case class Bank(age:Integer, job:String, marital : String, education : String, isdefault: String, balance : Integer, housing: String, loan:String, contact:String, month:String, day_of_week:String, duration: Integer, campaign:Integer, pdays:Integer, previous:Integer, poutcome:String, isSuccess:String)

val bankrdd = bankText.map(s=>s.split(";")).filter(s=>s(0)!="\"age\"").map(
s=>Bank(s(0).toInt,
 s(1).replaceAll("\"", ""),
  s(2).replaceAll("\"", ""),
   s(3).replaceAll("\"", ""),
   s(4).replaceAll("\"", ""),
  s(5).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt,
   s(6).replaceAll("\"", ""),
   s(7).replaceAll("\"", ""),
  s(8).replaceAll("\"", ""),
   s(9).replaceAll("\"", ""),
   s(10).replaceAll("\"", ""),
  s(11).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt,
   s(12).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt,
   s(13).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt,
  s(14).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt,
   s(15).replaceAll("\"", ""),
   s(16).replaceAll("\"", "")
)
)
val bankDF=bankrdd.toDF()
bankDF.printSchema()
```

Dataframe looks like below.

[image]

How to do feature engineering for column `age` and find right `age` effect on `campaign`?

Comment: Is the question about the process of feature engineering itself ?

Answer (score 2):

> I am working on a code assignment using Apache Spark.

Why don't you ask the mentor about the question then? It may help finding answers to this and future questions. Highly recommended.

> How to do feature engineering for column `age` and find right `age` effect on `campaign`?

First of all, I'd use the latest and greatest APIs from Spark SQL and Spark MLlib. Your life would be so much easier.

With that said (and my limited understanding of practical use of Machine Learning) I *think* that you should use [VectorAssembler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler) transformer to assemble the feature column.

> A feature transformer that merges multiple columns into a vector column.

From the official documentation about [VectorAssembler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler):

> `VectorAssembler` is a transformer that combines a given list of columns into a single vector column. It is useful for combining raw features and features generated by different feature transformers into a single feature vector, in order to train ML models like logistic regression and decision trees.